# firefox memory leak on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox, ram, memory-leak

Firefox consumes so much memory time to time, even when I'm just doing some web surfing that opens 5 tab, it consumes 1,6 GB of my RAM. Yeah maybe unused RAM is a waste.

But because of Firefox memory consumption, I cant open other programs and my system become unresponsive caused hang. My laptop has 4 GB of RAM (Ubuntu read it as 3.8 GB).

[image: firefox memory consumption]

[image: memory used by ubuntu almost 100%]

I test it by running chrome and check if the memory consumption is decreased if i open another programs. Is this usual behavior of Firefox?

P.S: i have try running firefox in safe mode.

Comment: Is that when running safe mode? How about a fresh profile? Or also running normal and install the "about:add-ons-memory" add-on to check the (sic) other add-ons?

Comment: no, its in normal mode. i have try running firefox in safe mode but same result, high memory usage with only several tab open

Comment: How much swap do you have set up? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of the `free` command.

Comment: I am see the same problem. I sometimes saw RAM usage going to 5 GB

Comment: A memory leak, if true, should be filed as a bug report. Seems off-topic here.